# Is there a manageable way of keeping track of loose code?

Tags: files

I program simple tasks everyday, but I have a hard time finding the scripts, and code snippets I write. Is there an manageable way to keep track of this sort of thing?

Comment: github.com has a gist function, which acts as a code snippet library

Comment: How do you handle scripts and code snippets for now? What kind is it, bash or powershell scripts, etc.?

Answer (score 6):

I use Mercurial for this. My work is on both Linux and Windows, so I have such small code snippets for both the system. I have created a repository on windows, on which I save all this scripts and then the clone of this on linux. I keep both in sync. 
Other than the use of DVCS, I also have a single csv text file which works as a key, value pair. The key is a small description of a program and value is it's location on the repository. Whatever I need I search in this file, and also keeps this file up-to-date. No need to tell that this file is also part of the repository. 
Let me warn you that, It has taken lots of efforts and discipline to make a habit of keeping things clean and neat. 
For Git lovers, I also love Git and also have repository in Github. It just that Mercurial is our official DVCS.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a VCS alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try bookmarking your code with reminder comments. That will help you a lot. Also there are a [variety of great source control management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) available in the market.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, a VCS alone is not enough for this. What your really need is a "database" of (possibly versioned) snippets or, even better, a "knowledge base" or a "wiki" of snippets like github's gist.

If you are in my same position, most likely you are not allowed to publish your code. In this case, you have to setup your own gist, either on your PC or on a server on your LAN.

Have a look at gitpaste for this:

http://www.gitpaste.com/

https://github.com/justinvh/gitpaste

There are other gist clones that can be used for this task, out there. You can also use one of those "desktop wiki" (or "mind mapping") programs that were so fashionable some years ago.

Everything that can help you to create a small, managed (and possibly versioned) "snippet base" will work fine.

Of course, if you are allowed to publish your snippets, you can just use gist.